# Choppy YouTube video and sound playback

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, video

I have issues with YouTube videos on Windows Server 2012 R2 via RDP, connected via a 2012 R2 RD GW server and UDP is enabled.
The videos play very choppy, no matter what quality I choose or browser (IE or Firefox).

It seems to be a issue like https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2585853 and [Server 2008 Std. Audio and Video very choppy on termials](https://serverfault.com/questions/272058/server-2008-std-audio-and-video-very-choppy-on-termials)

I've tried to give the server more CPU power, as IE using a lot when playing, but no difference.

I actually have the same issues on 2008 R2 servers in my environment.

Anybody had a issue like this?

Comment: Okay found this: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/433096-remote-desktop-server-2012-r2-ui-very-slow-for-user-only and disabled UDP in the firewall and it seems to running better now on the 2012 R2 servers. I'll do some tests.

Comment: Please be sure to post this as an answer to your own question if it works.

Comment: Yes, I know Twisty :)
But it seems to be a false positive, theres no difference today.